# What is 'that' referring to in the passage:

Tags: grammar, word-usage

What is  **that** referring back to in this paragraph ?
American feminist activists who have been described as "solitary" and "individual theorists" were in reality connected to a movement―utopian socialism—which was already popularizing feminist ideas in Europe during the two decades **that** culminated in the first women's rights conference held at Seneca Falls, New York, in 1848.

Comment: It doesn’t seem to be referring back past “the two decades”. It’s signalling more information about those two decades. Can you elaborate on why you think it is “referring back”?

Comment: @Lawrence I thought it was referring to Utopian socialism

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word “that” can be used in various ways (see [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/that?s=t)). Two of them are:

> 2 Referring to a specific thing previously mentioned, known, or understood.
> ‘that's a good idea’

> 5 **relative pronoun**
> Used instead of ‘which’, ‘who’, ‘whom’, or ‘when’ to introduce a defining clause, especially one essential to identification.
> ‘the woman that owns the place’

In your quote, if “that” referred back to “utopian socialism”, the author would be asserting that the culmination of utopian socialism lasted for the 2 decades associated with “the first women’s rights conference ...”. Although you can argue the ‘*that* = demonstrative’ case syntactically, it is more natural to treat the word *that* as a relative pronoun here.

Answer (score 1):

> [...] which was already popularizing feminist ideas in Europe during the two decades *that* culminated in the first women’s rights conference held at Seneca Falls.

“*That*” here refers to “the two decades”.

The two decades culminated in the first women’s rights conference held at Seneca Falls. “Culminate” means to reach a climax or point of highest development. In other words, the development of the first women’s rights conference reached a climax in the two decades.

Comment: So is it not referring to utopian socialism ?

Comment: No, I don’t think so. If it were referring to “utopian socialism”, or “a movement” as in the sentence, it should be: “[...] connected to a movement―utopian socialism—which was already popularizing feminist ideas in Europe during the two decades, **and which** culminated in the first women's rights conference held at Seneca Falls, New York, in 1848.” Honestly this sentence doesn’t seem to have any problem as well to me. (The first women’s rights conference being held marks the climax of the movement) But we’ve only got “that”, which most straightforwardly refers to “the two decades”.